# vba add blank space to excel cell

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I'm trying to add a white space into a excel formula with vba my code is this:

```
.Cells(row, col).Value = "=if(A1=0," & " " & ",'S1'!$D$1)"
```

this code add to my cell in excel this formula

```
=if(A1=0, ,'S1'!$D$1)
```

but I want something like this

```
"=if(A1=0," ",'S1'!$D$1)"
```

is this possible to do in vba ?

Comment: Replace the double quotes inside the True part of the If statement to single quotes.

Comment: I try with
.Cells(row, col).Value = "=if(A1=0," & '  ' & ",'S1'!$D$1)"
and
.Cells(row, col).Value = "=if(A1=0," & '" "' & ",'S1'!$D$1)" but I get an error of sintaxis

Comment: do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

`.Cells(row, col).Value = "=if(A1=0,"" "",'S1'!$D$1)"`

Comment: thx for comment i will try, but I actually get the result with this      .Cells(row, col).Value = "=if(A1=0," & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & ",'S1'!$D$1)"